# Multiprocessing without forking

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to use the Python multiprocessing module to communicate with child processes (via Pipes), which are independent of the caller (ie completely different and independent source code, path, executable).

The main process is doing some networking while the childs should simply do some data conversion (file in, file out). I need to do that several times a second, so restarting a subprocess for each file is no solution.

Is there a way to do that (under Windows)?

Comment: And the question is? `multiprocessing` works fine on windows, you simply have to use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom to avoid some code to be re-executed when launching child processes.

Comment: But multiprocessing tries to copy the Python environment (eg paths) from father process to child process. So the 2 process end up using similiar environment (and not working in my case)

Comment: Then I think you should rephrase your question, because I can't understand what is your problem. Could you provide an example of what you are obtaining now and what do you expect?